# Git and differing Vagrant files

Tags: git, vagrant

I have a Vagrant project in a Git repository, but require different Vagrant files for various machines. I'm wondering if there is a way to manage the Vagrant file in Git, rather than having to .gitignore the file and manage them outside of Git.

Comment: Well, a Vagrantfile is just Ruby right? So couldn't you just write some code to change the configuration depending on platform?

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a really good idea to put your Vagrantfile in source control, since it is often part of your dev and/or test environment.

It sounds like your problem is that each machine needs to make some customizations to the Vagrantfile to make it fit into their environment. This is a common issue – managing configuration files in source control. There's two main approaches:

- For things that have a small, discrete set of configurations (for instance, per platform), you can put that logic directly into the Vagrantfile. After all, Vagrantfiles are just Ruby code at the end of the day – feel free to put some configuration logic into them.
- For things that are unique to each individual user, it's best to source those from the environment through (for example) environment variables that the Vagrantfile can read through `ENV`. This way, you can commit the Vagrantfile and just require end users to configure their environment.

Comment: And host wide common configuration can be put into ~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile. Also the base boxes can include Vagrantfiles. All are merged. Consult [the documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would have different Vagrant files with their machine name appended to the filenames. Such as: `Vagrant.staging`, `Vagrant.development`, `Vagrant.production`, etc. When you go to deploy, just symlink the relative one to Vagrant.